# Pandas Pivot - Swap 'columns' and 'values'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I have a working pivot based upon the following code:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,
index=["row_a","row_b"], 
columns=["col_a"],
values=["metric_a", "metric_b"],
aggfunc={"metric_a":np.max, "metric_b":np.sum})
```

Based upon that code, I correctly receive the below output.

[image: current_pivot]

However, I would like to essentially swap the column with the metric to receive the below output.  Is this possible?

[image: desired_pivot]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think all you need is a call to [`pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) after the initial pivot, followed by sorting the columns to group the top level (level=0):

```
# Assuming df holds the result of the pivot
df.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: @PyNoob, yes, I've edited my answer: `df` is assumed to be the pivoted DF.

Comment: Hello sir, I just tried it and its close, but not exactly what I need.  This swaps the headers, but doesn't change the grouping.  As you can see in my desired screen shot, the metrics are grouped by the column values.  The swaplevel function doesn't handle that merging / ordering.

Comment: Ah, I see! I've edited my answer: the only required addition should be `.sort_index(axis=1)`