# Add Multiple Columns to a Pivot Table with pandas + python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a table with a list of products, their balances and prices, and I need to make a pivot table out of it.

I have table like this:

| Name | Model | Amount | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| audi | q5 | 1 | 18000 |
| audi | q7 | 5 | 22000 |

I'm trying to pivot it using pandas:

```py
data = pandas.read_excel("cars.xlsx")
data = data.pivot_table(values=['Amount', 'Price'], index='Name', columns='Model')
```

I get the table:

| Model | q5 | q7 | q5 | q7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name |  |  |  |  |
| audi | 1 | 5 | 18000 | 22000 |

But I want to get a table like this, but so that the columns with the model in the 1st row are merged:

|  | q5 | q5 | q7 | q7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | amount | price | amount | price |
| audi | 1 | 18000 | 5 | 22000 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you, based on the existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861081/pandas-pivot-swap-columns-and-values), just add the line

```py
data = data.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis="columns")
```